# word2vec_basic not working (Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec

I am new to word-embedding and Tensorflow. I am working on a project where I need to apply **word2vec** to health data.
I used the code for Tensorflow website ([`word2vec_basic.py`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w5GS.png)). I modified a little this code to make it read my data instead of "text8.zip" and it runs normally until the last step:

```py
num_steps = 100001

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
# We must initialize all variables before we use them.
  tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
  print('Initialized')
  average_loss = 0
  for step in range(num_steps):
    batch_data, batch_labels = generate_batch(
      batch_size, num_skips, skip_window)
    feed_dict = {train_dataset : batch_data, train_labels : batch_labels}
    _, l = session.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
    average_loss += l
    if step % 2000 == 0:
      if step > 0:
        average_loss = average_loss / 2000
      # The average loss is an estimate of the loss over the last 2000 batches.
      print('Average loss at step %d: %f' % (step, average_loss))
      average_loss = 0
    # note that this is expensive (~20% slowdown if computed every 500 steps)
    if step % 10000 == 0:
     sim = similarity.eval()
     for i in range(valid_size):
       valid_word = reverse_dictionary[valid_examples[i]]
       top_k = 8 # number of nearest neighbors
       nearest = (-sim[i, :]).argsort()[1:top_k+1]
       log = 'Nearest to %s:' % valid_word
       for k in range(top_k):
         close_word = reverse_dictionary[nearest[k]]
         log = '%s %s,' % (log, close_word)
       print(log)
  final_embeddings = normalized_embeddings.eval()<code>
```

This code is exactly the same as the example so I don't think it is wrong. the error It gave is:

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-fc4c5c915fc6> in <module>()
     34         for k in xrange(top_k):
     35           print(nearest[k])
---> 36           close_word = reverse_dictionary[nearest[k]]
     37           log_str = "%s %s," % (log_str, close_word)
     38         print(log_str)

KeyError: 2868
```

I changed the size of the input data but it still gives the same error.
I would really appreciate if someone could give me some advice on how to fix this problem.

Comment: It means your reverse_dictionary doesn't have a 2868th element. It is a little strange since nearest[k] should be chosen from dictionary words. I think you better upload whole your source code. Otherwise check dictionary size and valid_examples.

Comment: Thank Jin, I found where it went wrong but still don't know how to fix. I used exactly as example "word2vec_basic" of website. But in the step  "text8.zip", I deleted some lines of this file so that It only have 2/5 length as original text. and the error appeared. And you are right my dictionary only have 2045 elements. Is 2868 is the minimum length for skip-diagram model work ?

Comment: I don't think so. The word id 2868 is randomly chosen from your dictionary.
So it shouldn't be larger than 2045. That is why I recommend you to upload whole part of your source code. Something must be wrong. I guess.

Comment: Thanks Jin, here is my code: filename = 'text9.zip'. 
    def read_data(filename):
      """Extract the first file enclosed in a zip file as a list of words"""
  with zipfile.ZipFile(filename) as f:
    data = tf.compat.as_str(f.read(f.namelist()[0])).split()
  return data
  
words = read_data(filename)
print('Data size %d' % len(words))

Comment: The code is no different from Tensorflow website. I just copied it from github, but only change the file input by skipping down load file "text8.zip". Instead, I created "text9.zip" in directory and read it as the code above. The rest is unchange.

Comment: I check the dictionary of sample code, and Its size is 5000 while my dictionary size is only 2045. DO you think because the step-size, num_steps, batch_size are only fit with 5000, so when I apply different dictionary size. The numbers are not suitable ?

Comment: Oh, OK. Now I understand the sample doesn't think about the case. You have to resize the similarity tensor. I will give you how to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the vocabulary size is less than default maximum (50000), you should modify the number.

At the last of step 2, let's modify vocabulary_size to actual dictionary size.

```
data, count, dictionary, reverse_dictionary = build_dataset(words)
del words  # Hint to reduce memory.
print('Most common words (+UNK)', count[:5])
print('Sample data', data[:10], [reverse_dictionary[i] for i in data[:10]])

#add this line to modify
vocabulary_size = len(dictionary)
print('Dictionary size', len(dictionary))
```

Comment: You are right, It fixed the code.I do not full understand the logic of this code. Thanks you very much. Just a quick question: num_steps = 100001 and if statement check every 2000 step. Does it affect anything since my data only 2087 ?

Comment: That's great. I don't think num_steps nor checking steps affect your program.

Comment: Thanks, anyway I need to understand the code before any further